# Django. How to EXCLUDE one-to-many or many-to-many fields from query?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a sample model like this:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField ...
    age = models.IntegerField ...
    cats = models.ManyToManyField ...
    dogs = models.ManyToManyField ...
```

As u can see, there is 2 many-to-many fields (cats, dogs)

Then (somewhere else in my code) I have serializer function which converts given model into JSON. Eg.

```
make_json(foobar_instance) will produce smth like this:

{
    "id": "9999",
    "name": "John Romero",
    "age": "55",
    "cats": "[421, 5423, 53252]",
    "dogs": "[213, 44124, 321, 753]"
}
```

BUT I don't need that "cats" and "dogs" fields in my result JSON and I don't want to charge database with additional queries for resolving that many-to-many relations.

So, how I can tell Django: Man, exclude that cats and dogs fields from result - I don't need that thing.

Eg.

```
FooBar.objects.filter(....).SKIP('cats', 'dogs')...
```

Is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Django's ORM will not issue sql queries to retrieve the related objects until you try to access them or unless you specifically asked for them using `select_related()` and/or `prefetch_related()`, so the simplest solution could be to inspect the model instance's fields in your `make_json()` function (using `._meta.get_fields()`) to exclude `ForeignKey` and `Many2ManyField` fields from your serialization.

Comment: Yes - you right - queries are lazy. One problem that I'm using an external serializer which I can't modify. And also - your response looks like a good realization. Thank you.

Comment: Python is quite dynamic so I'd be suprised if you really couldn't "modify" the serializer one way or another - at least monkeypatching it (ugly yes, but sometimes a real lifesaver).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are `defer()` or `only()` methods of QuerySet.

`defer()` - omits the fields retrieved from the database.

`only()` - returns only specified fields from the database.

In your case:
`FooBar.objects.defer('cats', 'dogs').filter(...)`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer

Answer (score -1):

So... After few hours of thinking, here is what I get:

```
# Getting list of model fields
# and excluding cats and dogs from this list.
result_fields = [f.name for f in FooBar._meta.get_fields()]
result_fields.remove('cats')
result_fields.remove('dogs')

# Making query.
FooBar.objects.values(*result_fields).filter(....)
```

One bad thing that python dict is returned instead of QuerySet, but maybe this will be enough for many cases.